# Changing TextWrapping property of a TextBlock inside a GridView

Tags: xaml, uwp

I have a `GridView` with a `TextBlock` and a `Button`. For now, the `MinWidth` of the `GridView`'s `DataTemplate` is fixed. The `TextWrapping` property of the `TextBlock` ss set to `Wrap`.

It looks like 
[image: this:]

the last `DataTemplate` has more text to show ( wrapping is ON ).

What I want to do is, if I tap on a text block and it has more text to show then it will expand ( in height ) to show the full text. For this, I thought to toggle its `TextWrapping` property on tap. But it doesn't seem to work this way.

Here's my XAML:

```
<GridView Name="TagsGridView"                           
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind TagsList, Mode=OneWay}"
        SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
            <Grid Background="#1A503E"
                  MinWidth="150">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}"
                            Grid.Column="0"     
                            Height="Auto"
                            TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                            TextWrapping="Wrap"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"                                               
                            Foreground="White"
                            Padding="10"
                            Tapped="TextBlock_Tapped"/>
                <Button Content="&#xE10A;" 
                        Name="btnTagDelete"
                        Click="btnTagDelete_Click"
                        Foreground="White"
                        Grid.Column="1"                                             
                        Width="40"
                        Height="40"  
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

And here's my tapped event:

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
            if (textBlock.TextWrapping == TextWrapping.Wrap) textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.NoWrap;
            else textBlock.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
        }
```

This causes the textblock to show some more text but doesn't change the height due to which all the text is not shown. I also tried to increase the height of `TextBlock` arbitrarily like this:

```
private void TextBlock_Tapped(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBlock = sender as TextBlock;
    textBlock.Height = 1000;
}
```

Doing this does increase the height of the template by hardly 20 (unit) but then the `Text` inside the `TextBlock` becomes blank.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Each item in a `GridView` with the default `ItemTemplate` has the exact same height n width. If you don't need virtualization, try `VariableSizedWrapGrid` instead.

Comment: As above, the default GridView panel (ItemsWrapGrid) sizes items to the size of the first item if no fixed size is given.

However, you'd be better suited with some implemention of a WrapPanel than a VariableSizedWrapGrid - IF you don't need virtualization. If you do... you have to handle it manually.

Comment: @JustinXL will that provide the toggle functionality ?

Comment: The toggling should be handled by each individual `Tag` control. And @JohnnyWestlake is right, a `WrapPanel` is a better choice here. Actually, I implemented almost the exact same tagging UI with the `WrapPanel` from the [UWP Community Toolkit](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/WrapPanel/).  I'd only suggest that instead of wrapping them to multiple lines, maybe try with just one line but trim the text by default, and expand to full width on tap. Because if one item is much taller you will end up having a lot of gaps on the UI which won't look nice.